# How to warn someone of a script failure, without email?

Tags: bash, automation

I have a script that does hourly backup and sign-encrypting of my Keepass DB on my headless Mac Mini with this code :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

DATE=$(gdate +"%d%m%y_%H%M")
LDATE=$(gdate --rfc-3339=seconds)
DIR="/Users/stig124/Sec"
FILENAME="/Users/stig124/bak/secbak-$DATE.tar.xz"
KEY="<REDACTED>"

cd /Users/stig124 || exit

gtar cJf "$FILENAME" "$DIR"
gpg --yes --batch -r "$KEY" --passphrase-file /Users/stig124/pkx  --output "$FILENAME".enc --encrypt --sign "$FILENAME"

if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
    echo "Encryption failed"
    exit
else
    find /Users/stig124/bak/ -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
fi

rclone copy "$FILENAME".enc G2D:/backup

if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
    echo "Export failed"
    exit
else
    echo "Everything fine"
    rm -f "$FILENAME"
fi
```

I know that the main way of notifying errors is email, but I can't do a mail server on any of my machines (behind a non-functional NAT (I can't open any port on my router without any clear reason)).

I thought about using `AppleScript` with Apple Mail but I don't want to link any accounts with that machine (and even if I did, I won't use Apple Mail anyways)

So I have absolutely no idea how to deal with that, I can transform that program in Python and use a like Discord Webhook that could communicate the options but I would like something in Bash if possible

Comment: The general alternative to scripts sending notifications themselves is for them to record their success/failure in a way that can be recognised up by your existing monitoring solution. Using your monitoring solution generally also offers you better management of notifications than email messages.

Comment: You should be able to run a transmit-only mail server from behind NAT, but you'll probably have to take extra steps to avoid getting blocked as spam.

Comment: Can you use curl to deliver the Discord Webhook? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62227905/using-curl-in-the-cmd-to-send-a-discord-webhook

Comment: This seems unclear. If your NAT is unable to pass through mail traffic, surely all other traffic will be impossible too?